# Nimbus JTree presentation error under java version 1.8

Tags: java, swing, jtree, look-and-feel, nimbus

right now I am establishing the Nimbus Look and Feel to an Application which is already in use for some time.
The Application contains some `JTree`s which I want to have to display vertical and horizontal lines.

Under java version 1.7 which I used earlier this was easy to set up with those specific entries in the `UIDefaults`:

- `UIManager.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);`

and

- `UIManager.put("Tree.drawHorizontalLines", true);`

As implied above this works totally fine as long as I am using a jre with the verion 1.7, as soon as I use 1.8 the vertical lines in the `JTree` wont get displayed.

I just wanted to ask if anybody knows if this a known issue of Nimbus under java 1.8 and if so, does anyone know a solution or workaround to this problem?

EDIT: Here some example code to clarify my Problem:

```
public class test 
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    UIManager.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);
    UIManager.put("Tree.drawHorizontalLines", true);
    UIManager.put("Tree.linesStyle", "dashed");

    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    top.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Branch1"));
    top.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Branch2"));
    top.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Branch3"));
    ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)top.getFirstChild()).add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Leaf1"));
    ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)top.getFirstChild()).add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Leaf2"));


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTree tree = new JTree(top);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(450,300));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
    frame.add(scroll);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

This is just an example code, not the actual software I am currently working at, so I think the issue is up to a mistake I did in both codes or its some problem with the java-version 1.8.

The usage of jdk1.7 and jdk1.8 leads to two different results:

**jdk1.7**

[image: jdk1.7]

**jdk1.8**

[image: jdk1.8]

As you can see the horizontal lines in the 1.8-version are missing.

Sorry for bad grammar, I´m no native speaker.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is unknown (bug?), but it seems to work fine for me using `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);` instead of `UIManager.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);` (jdk1. 8.0_131 on Windows 10):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NimbusDrawVerticalLinesTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      // UIManager.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);
      UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);
      UIManager.put("Tree.drawHorizontalLines", true);
      UIManager.put("Tree.linesStyle", "dashed");

      JTree tree = new JTree();
//       UIDefaults d = new UIDefaults();
//       d.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", Boolean.TRUE);
//       tree.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);

      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tree));
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: hey that actually did solve my problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround to this problem.
I just have implemented my own SynthTreeUI-class and overwritten the "paintVerticalPartOfLeg()"-method.

I have adopted the code out of the BasicTreeUI-class nearly one-to-one with two little differences.

There are two conditions in this class which I had to delete in order to make it work for my program, because I had no access to the variables of the super class.

As soon as I deleted these parts the appearence of the JTree went back to normal.

Here the code snippets mentioned above:

```
if (!paintLines) {
    return;
}
```

and

```
if (leftToRight) {
      lineX = lineX - getRightChildIndent() + insets.left;
}
else {
     lineX = tree.getWidth() - lineX - insets.right +
                  getRightChildIndent() - 1;
}
```

Because there was no exception thrown at runtime, I guess its probably the first one which causes the issue.

"paintLines" is a boolean attribute which proves if the following Property is set to true:

- UIManager.getBoolean("Tree.paintLines")

But even though I set the value of this property to true, it still didn´t work I had to create my own TreeUI-class.

I compared the source code of the BasicTreeUI-class from both versions to each other but couldn´t find any differences in the "paintVerticalPartOfLeg()"-method nor how the attribute "paintLines" is been handled.

So I solved the problem for me, but Im still not sure what exactly caused the problem in the first place.

Are you even able to reconstruct my Problem or does it only affect me?

I dont think that I have the time to check further on this issue in the near future, so I would appreciate if anyone who gets to find out what causes the issue, would post it in this thread.